# Error upon starting tsserver in VS Code: "TSServer exited. Code: null. Signal: SIGTERM"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsserver

When starting tsserver vs code fails although it picks up the right version.

```
2023-08-25 16:18:16.644 [info] Starting TS Server undefined
2023-08-25 16:18:16.644 [info] Using tsserver from: c:\Users\Stratos\Desktop\QA\repos\lh\cypress\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js undefined
2023-08-25 16:18:16.644 [info] <syntax> Forking...
2023-08-25 16:18:16.644 [info] <syntax> Starting...
2023-08-25 16:18:16.644 [info] <semantic> Forking...
2023-08-25 16:18:16.644 [info] <semantic> Starting...
2023-08-25 16:18:16.645 [error] TSServer exited. Code: null. Signal: SIGTERM
```

[image]

From the `settings.json`:

```json
"typescript.tsdk": "c:\\Users\\Stratos\\Desktop\\QA\\repos\\lh\\cypress\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib",
```

Actual file path:

`C:\Users\Stratos\Desktop\QA\repos\lh\cypress\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js`

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/161291 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171156. please follow the steps in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171156#issuecomment-1385850632. If you raise an issue ticket of your own, please ping me with a link to it.

Comment: @starball thank you, issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191441

Comment: the VS Code maintainers commented on your issue ticket and asked for more info. I suggest you speedily respond with that info. Issue tickets that are waiting on info too long will get get closed.

Comment: For me it was fixed after updating VSCode/Codium

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue ticket where this is being tracked is [TSServer exited
#191441](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191441).

[One user reports](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191441#issuecomment-1801068334) that they are able to work around the issue by reloading VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload with Extensions Disabled` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), then closing VS Code, and then reopening it. Since that works, I also wonder if using the `TypeScript: Restart TS Server` or `TypeScript: Reload Project` commands in the command palette work. It might also have to do with running in WSL.

[One user reports](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191441#issuecomment-1713701806) that they get a similar issue when they simultaneously enable the Deno extension.

Comment: Disabling extensions also fixed the issue for me, I wonder why this works?

Comment: @Athe can you try the two typescript VS Code commands that I just added into the answer post via edit?

Comment: thanks, I tried but no luck.
I am also finding that disabling extensions does not actually work. I am investigating other ways to fix the issue.

Comment: for me it was fixed by running on windows host instead of in WSL2. Not sure why though.